# How to change the default shortcut name in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

So we have a share folder that we import all of our database tables into and then each of the developers have their own development folder and they just create shortcuts to the source tables and target tables they need. I have been trying to find a way to change the default shortcut name (i.e. Shortcut_to_nameoftable). I am talking about about the Informatica Powercenter Designer.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: +1, because I also would like to use a different default name, but I'm afraid it's not possible.

Comment: it's one of those things that should be modifiable but i have yet to find anyway to change it

Answer (score 0):

I know you will definitely know the answer by now, but I hope this helps someone. 
You can change the default name "Shorcut_to_tablename" in Source Analyzer. Right-click->Edit->Rename.

Comment: Hi Shibani, I know how to change the name of a source definition. What this post was about was changing the default shortcut name. Every time I create a shortcut the name is prefixed with "shortcut_to_" and I would like to change this prefix to something else.